# Retrieving 'Creation Date' metadata from a Word file that has been written to PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, metadata

I have recently received a letter as a PDF document. The letter date does not match the file metadata, but I suspect the original letter was written in Word.

Is there a way to extract the date the original Word file was created from the metadata?

My searches suggested that document creation date is preserved, but a test I ran with one of my old Word files showed today as the creation date once written to PDF.

Any help is much appreciated.

Kind regards!

Comment: Where have you seen that the Word document's creation date is preserved?

Comment: Using the command line, you could try [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) with this command:  `exiftool -time:all -G1 -a -s file.pdf`  That will show all the date/time tags in the pdf.

Comment: The Creation date in a Word file is not all that reliable anyway. It can be changed accidentally and can also be changed deliberately. Additionally, if the date printed in the letter was set using a DATE field, it will automatically be the date Word was opened with that document and has nothing to do with the creation date.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.

I was unable to retrieve it with exiftool, but thanks all the same. It retrieved the available PDF metadata. Thanks all the same, StarGeek.

Thanks for the explanation Charles.